# Why does the function look like this and is there a general name for such functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-numbers

[image]

[image]

What is going on as x goes to infinity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function has a polynomial in the numerator and a trigonometric function in the denominator; I don't know of any special name for that type.  Since trigonometric functions are periodic, and $\sin x$ has two zeroes in each period, then you are dividing by $0$ over and over, and in particular faster and faster, as $x^2$ increases more and more rapidly.  That's why you are getting all those spikes to $\infty$ and $-\infty$.

The graph is even messier than what is shown, because of the resolution limit on your graph.